# Upper bound of $\frac{\sum_i c_ia_ie_i}{\sum_i d_ib_if_i}$?

Tags: inequalities, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $\sum_i c_i =\sum_i d_i=1$, where $c_i,d_i \ge 0$. Assume that $\frac{\sum_i c_ia_i}{\sum_i d_ib_i} \le \epsilon_1$ and $\frac{\sum_i c_ie_i}{\sum_i d_if_i} \le \epsilon_2$, where $a_i,b_i,e_i,f_i \ge 0$. How to give an upper bound of the quantity
$$\frac{\sum_i c_ia_ie_i}{\sum_i d_ib_if_i},$$
where the bound is the function of $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2$.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such upper bound in general. E.g., take $c_1=c_2=d_1=d_2=\frac12$ (or any other nonzero values), $b_1=f_2=1$ and $b_2=f_1=0$, which nullify the denominator of the fraction being bounded, while both fractions given as conditions are finite.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have spent several days to treat the problem. Your counterexample lets me not to waste further time about it. Now, I'm considering give the problem other constraints to bound it.

Comment: What about if adding the constraints $\frac{a_i}{b_i} \le \xi_i$ and $\frac{e_i}{f_i}\le \eta_i$?

Comment: Still doesn't help.  Half the b_i and half the f_i could be away from zero, but all of the b_i f_i could be small enough to make the denominator near zero.  Gerhard "Work Together For Greater Results" Paseman, 2017.04.29.